# Windows form project not recognizing class from another project

Tags: c#

I am currently working on a project requiring me to have my classes and GUI in different projects. I am getting an error cs1061 telling me :

> 'Categorie' does not contain a definition for 'AddCategory' and no accessible extension method 'AddCategory' accepting a first argument of type 'Categorie' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

```
using HiTechLibrary_Library.BLL;
```

Here is the code I have for the "Add Button"

```
private void buttonAddCategory_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string catName = textBoxName.Text.Trim();
        if (!Validator.ValidEmployeeName(catName))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid Name Format !", "Error");
            textBoxName.Clear();
            textBoxName.Focus();
            return;
        }

        try
        {
            Categorie cat = new Categorie();
            cat.CategoryName = catName;
            cat.**AddCategory**(cat);
            
            MessageBox.Show("New Category added auccesfully !", "Success");
            textBoxName.Clear();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

The Issue here is with AddCategory not being recognized.

Here is the class containing AddCategorie

```
namespace HiTechLibrary_Library.BLL
{
    public class Categorie
    {
        private int categoryId;
        private string categoryName;

        public int CategoryId { get => categoryId; set => categoryId = value; }
        public string CategoryName { get => categoryName; set => categoryName = value; }

        public List<Categorie> CategoryList()
        {
            return CategorieDB.GetCategoryList();
        }
        public Categorie SearchCategory(int cat_id)
        {
            return CategorieDB.SearchCategory(cat_id);
        }
        public static void AddCategorie(Categorie cat)
        {
            CategorieDB.AddCategory(cat);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could it have something to with methods name being AddCategorie vs AddCategory?

Comment: @Jawad I thought it was at first. I went through everything and it does not seem to be the problem.

Comment: Did you add a _reference_ from one project to the other, just like the error message asks?

Comment: @JohnAlexiou Yes, I did add a reference.

Comment: Why the `static` keyword in `public static void AddCategorie(Categorie cat);`? The other methods do not have it?

Comment: The issue seems to be method being static. You should access the static method directly from class.

Comment: the `AddCategorie` method is static. Remove the static keyword and it should work

Answer (score 0):

Try separating the Entity from the Handler, like this

```
public class Category
{
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
}


public class CategoryHandler
{
    public List<Category> GetCategoryList()
    {
        return CategorieDB.GetCategoryList();
    }
    public Category SearchCategory(int cat_id)
    {
        return CategorieDB.SearchCategory(cat_id);
    }
    public void AddCategory(Category cat)
    {
        CategorieDB.AddCategory(cat);
    }
}
```

You call it like this:

```
var cat = new Category();
cat.CategoryName = catName;

var catHandler = new CategoryHandler()
catHandler.AddCategory(cat);
```

Comment: No, that syntax in the OPs code will still find a static function.

Comment: @Nathan answer is updated, you should receive an error but this new error should be related to your Generic list as it needs to be updated to be a type of Category

Comment: @Nathan check the last update please, it may help.

Comment: @U8080 I have tried your code and it does not seem to change anything on my end.

Comment: @Nathan error message should be different. You need to check on the CategorieDB repository as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `static` keyword from `AddCategorie()`

```
public void AddCategorie(Categorie cat)
{
    CategorieDB.AddCategory(cat);
}
```